# ¿Solucion windows forms con diferentes versiones de framework?

Tags: c#

Actualmente cuento con una solución con varios proyectos de Windows Forms la mayoria esta hecho en Framework 3.5, ahora quiero incluir un proyecto a dicha solución pero en versión 4.6.1.
¿Esto es posible? o tendré problemas de compatibilidad, 
de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Depende de que tan estrecha sea la relacionan de tus proyectos puede que te de algún conflicto, de otra forma no veo el problema

Comment: Recomendaria normalices las versiones llevando todas a la version mas actualizada, entiendo simplemente serie cambiar la version que usas desde las propiedades